# In MS Access How to fetch data in the other row in same table based on what i select in first row?

Tags: ms-access

i am a beginner at MS Access. I would like to know what is the possible way that to fetch data automatically based on what i select from another row in the same table. I have table as like below.

ID (autonumber)
Airlines (short text)
FlightNumber (short text)

From above case, there could be many flight numbers under an airline. Therefore, in my table, i have entered many flight numbers for same airline. What i want to do is like, when i select a flight number in a dropdown list, i want to database to select correct Airline based on data i have entered in the table.

Any held would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you need is, Cascading ComboBoxes. Where ComboBoxes cascade based on the selections made previously. I am expanding your example. For simplicity, I have a form with only two ComboBox controls. The table which has the flight info is **tbl_FlightInfo**. Let us say it has the following structure.

```
flightID    |   flightCompany   |   flightName
------------+-------------------+--------------
1           |   British Airways |   BA500
2           |   British Airways |   BA707
3           |   Qatar Airways   |   QA200
4           |   Virgin Atlantic |   VA303
5           |   Virgin Atlantic |   VA404
```

The first ComboBox (flightCompanyCombo), would have the RowSource as,

```
SELECT flightCompany FROM tbl_FlightInfo GROUP BY tbl_FlightInfo;
```

This will list all the company you have in the table, the second ComboBox (flightNameCombo) could have a RowSource as,

```
SELECT flightName FROM tbl_FlightInfo;
```

Now this is to make sure the ComboBox is populated with all Flight names initially. Then in the AfterUpdate event of the **flightCompanyCombo**, you can requery the **flightNameCombo**, the code would be something like,

```
Private Sub flightNameCombo_AfterUpdate()
    Me.flightNameCombo.RowSource = "SELECT flightName FROM tbl_FlightInfo " & _
                                   "WHERE flightCompany = '" & Me.flightNameCombo & "'"
    Me.flightNameCombo.ReQuery
End Sub
```

This way if you select ***British Airways*** in Company Name Combo, the Flight Name combo, will have ***BA500*** and ***BA707***.

For more information :

1. http://www.utteraccess.com/wiki/index.php/Cascading_Combo_Boxes
2. http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/forms/combo-boxes/cascading.html
3. http://www.fontstuff.com/access/acctut10.htm

Comment: Thank you very much i will try on it. and post you the results